# Use ubuntu server 10.04 as a virtulization server as esxi from VMWare

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization

I was wondering if its possible to use Ubuntu server as virtualization center as ESXi Vmware? 
I am asking this coz i read this in ubuntu website:

"Ubuntu includes a Virtual Machine Builder which makes this process simple and replicable allowing multiple pre-configured machines to be deployed instantly".

## If its possible how can i do such thing?.

with all respect.
Hitham Melhem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu as a virtualization host is more comparable with VMware Server than ESXi, since you're not running on bare-metal.

Check out this document which describes KVM, a common virtualization method for Ubuntu, which is probably what you've read about:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM

Answer (score 0):

Nice use of font size there hitham, the answer is no, VMWare vSphere vCenter is a Windows application only.

Comment: thank you but the font was made by wrong but thanks again for your responding .

Answer (score 0):

ESXi installs directly onto bare metal - not into a host OS. Installing ESXi into a VM inside VMware Server *might* (<sub><sup>theoretically</sup></sub>) be possible - but I wouldn't try.

Comment: AFAIK you can install ESXi in a VM, but it won't let you start any VMs on the VM (if you know what I mean)

Comment: will it? I've not tried, but I thought it relied on direct access to the virtualizing features of the underlying processor